# If string is less than date yields all dates or none

Tags: bash, date, if-statement, while-loop

I have a log file with a custom date format, in which I'm pulling out the dates to see if they preceed a certain time period, and if so to print them.  Unfortunately I can only get it to print everything or nothing.

```
deldate=$(date +"%m/%d/%Y %T" -d "-92 hours")
awk '{ if ("$6 $7" < "$deldate") print $6, $7}' srbilltest.txt
echo "Delete Date:" $deldate;
```

Source file example.

```
field1 field2 field3 field4 field5 3/24/2015 1:42:00
field1 field2 field3 field4 field5 3/25/2015 1:42:00
field1 field2 field3 field4 field5 3/26/2015 1:42:00
field1 field2 field3 field4 field5 3/27/2015 1:42:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to use a shell variable inside your awk script but going about it in the wrong way. Try changing your script to this:

```
deldate=$(date +"%m/%d/%Y %T" -d "-92 hours")
awk -v d="$deldate" '"$6 $7" < d {print $6, $7}' srbilltest.txt
```

This creates a variable `d` in awk, using the value of the shell variable `$deldate`. Note that `$`s are not used to access the value of the variable in awk; the `$` is reserved for accessing fields like `$6` as you have done.

As an aside, I've removed the `if` from your awk code as the structure of an awk program is `condition { action }` anyway.

While the code above solves the problem of using the shell variable inside awk, there is another issue, which is that your comparison will fail when the year changes. You should consider changing your date format to something like [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), so that it begins with the year.

Alternatively, if you are using GNU awk, you could use [`mktime`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html) like this:

```
deldate=$(date +%s -d "-92 hours")
awk -v d="$deldate" '{split($6,a,"/");split($7,b,":")}
    mktime(a[3]" "a[1]" "a[2]" "b[1]" "b[2]" "b[3]) < d{print $6, $7}' file
```

Depending on the contents of the other fields, it may be possible to change your field separator and avoid the calls to `split`.

Comment: Bingo, your first solution I couldn't get to work, the second however works perfectly Tom.  I couldn't quite figure out how to get mktime to work for me, it's a bit beyond my knowledge yet.